# Changing shipping fields values in WooCommerce doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In my WooCommerce store I have an external API with the map for picking shipping address. After user choose place of delivery on the map, shipping address is send from client to server using AJAX.

Here's my Javascript functions invoked every time user change shipping address:

```
const changeShippingAddress = (address, postalCode, city) => {
    wp.ajax.post( "change_shipping_address", {
        address,
        postalCode,
        city
    } )
        .done(function(response) {
            alert(response);
        })
        .fail(err => {
            alert("fail");
            alert(err);
        });
}
```

And here's my PHP code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_change_shipping_address', 'mytheme_change_shipping_address' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_change_shipping_address', 'mytheme_change_shipping_address' );

function mytheme_change_shipping_address() {
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_address($_POST['address']);
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode($_POST['postalCode']);
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_city($_POST['city']);

    wp_send_json_success('success');
}
```

Values are sending properly from client to server with AJAX (I can read them on server side and send them back to client with `wp_send_json_success`), but the problem is, shipping fields aren't updated (after sending form, error about empty shipping fields shows up). Why is that happened? Is something wrong with my `set_shipping` functions?